# Highlight entire word in R Studio, including backticks, underscores, and other special characters

Tags: r, ide, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts, highlight

I'm a heavy keyboard shortcut user (I loathe using the mouse when editing code especially). In R Studio one of the things I often want to do is highlight and select an entire variable name.  When the variable name consists of just letters and/or underscores and/or periods, I can easily highlight to select an entire variable name by simply pressing `Ctrl+Shift+{RA}` or `Ctrl+Shift+{LA}` on a Windows PC, where `{RA}` is the right arrow key and `{LA}` is the left arrow key.  The R Studio Keyboard Shortcuts menu refers to these two shortcuts as "Select Next Word" and "Select Previous Word," respectively.  For example, if I want to highlight the variable name `var2_attribute` in the code below:

**Example 1**

```
example1 <- var2_attribute
```

I simply move my cursor to the left of the "v" in `var2_attribute`, press `Ctrl+Shift+{RA}` and the entire variable is selected as desired and shown below.

[image]

However, if I encounter a variable that has some non-standard characters in it like a backtick, or a curly brace, and I attempt to use the same keyboard shortcut to highlight the entire variable, only portions of the variable are highlighted (up to the special characters, typically).  So if I want to highlight the entire word, I have to press `Ctrl+Shift+{RA}` several times until I reach the end of the variable name that I'm highlighting.  For example, when I attempt to highlight the entire variable `` `an_example_var` `` including the backticks, using `Ctrl+Shift+{RA}` after placing my cursor to the left of the left-most backtick, only the first backtick is initially highlighted.  When I press the Right Arrow key again, the middle portion of the variable name, `an_example_var` is highlighted, and when I press the Right Arrow key again, the entire variable name is selected (what I was hoping to achieve with a single keyboard shortcut, rather than three sequential keystrokes of `Ctrl+Shift+{RA}`).  The images below show this behavior in two separate examples that highlight (pun intended) my frustration:

**Example 2**

- First Keystroke Combination:

[image]

- Second Keystroke Combination:

[image]

- Third Keystroke Combination:
  [image]

**Example 3**

- First Keystroke Combination:
  [image]
- Second Keystroke Combination
  [image]
- Third Keystroke Combination
  [image]
- Fourth Keystroke Combination
  [image]
- Fifth Keystroke Combination
  [image]

Note in Example 3, when I press the fifth and final keystroke combination, the highlighting actually overshoots the second double-quote and highlights the final parenthesis, when I was thinking from a logical standpoint, it would stop at the final closing double-quote.

**ASK:  Is there any way to change my settings or add a keyboard shortcut that will highlight and entire valid R variable name (typically when white space or a second backtick is encountered if the variable name has spaces surrounded by backticks)?  If so, could you provide some brief instruction on how I might go about setting this up?**  It seems a bit tedious for me to have to press the keyboard shortcut five times to highlight a single variable name (and even then it's overshooting my intended highlight).

Comment: If you’re a heavy keyboard user you might be more happy using Vim than RStudio: RStudio doesn’t even come *close* to the power and ergonomics of keyboard use afforded by Vim (even when using “Vim keybindings” in RStudio). However, getting Vim to work as well as RStudio for R development takes some (occasionally frustrating) setup. The relevant plugins you’ll want are AstroNvim & Nvim-R.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Yes, I used to vim quite a bit, but haven't in some time.  I do use a number of different editors including vim, SublimeText, and Visual Studio.  I think I tried using vim with R Studio a while back and found it frustrating and abandoned my efforts.  I think it's time to explore it again with some more patience.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your critical examples work for me with `Ctrl+Shift+Up`.

If you are into fast editing, you might want to consider enabling vim mode in RStudio or even better: just switch to vim ;).

Comment: Wow.  This is what I've been missing the up arrow, does in fact seem to highlight the entire variable!  Thank you so much.  Thanks for the helpful advice on vim as well.  I actually do use vim -- as well as a number of other editors including SublimeText and Visual Studio Code that make coding all that much easier.  I haven't used vim for some time, but you're right -- I need to switch back.  Thank again!

Comment: Well, RStudio is really hard to beat! I use both, RStudio and nvim-R, depending on what I am working on. Sometimes, if I have to do heavy editing, I just fire up vim directly in the RStudio console and edit there. Overall, the shortcuts of RStudio are pretty good, and the other features are just unbelievably good if you compare it to other languages.